# How to build ng2-select cascading dropdownlist

Tags: angular

I want to build a cascading dropdown using ng2-select. I am able to get the individual dropdowns to work but when I attempt to place two or more in the same view only the first one works the second one doesn't

```
import { SelectComponent } from "ng2-select/ng2-select";
import { SelectItem } from 'ng2-select/components/select/select-item';
export class AdministrativeStructureComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{
  @ViewChild(SelectComponent)
  private selectCountry: SelectComponent;
  private selectTier: SelectComponent;

   //Country
private countryValue: any = {};
private _countryDisabledV: string = '0';
private countryDisabled: boolean = false;
private countryItems: Array<any> = [];

constructor(
    private tierService: TierService,
    private adminStructService: AdministrativeStructureService ,
    private itemsService: ItemsService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.administrativeStructure = new AdministrativeStructure();
    this.tier = new Tier();
    this.parentTier = new Tier();
    this.GetCountries();
}
GetTiers(countryID: string) {
    this.tierService.GetTierSelect(countryID)
        .subscribe((res: TierSelectViewModel[]) => {
            this.tiers = res;
            this.tiers.forEach((tier: Tier) => {
               // console.log(tier.TierName + "====================================================================================");
                this.tierItems.push(tier.TierName);
                this.selectTier.itemObjects.push(new SelectItem({ id: tier.TierID, text: tier.TierName }));
            }, error => {
                this.notificationService.printErrorMessage("Failed to Load Tier Information " + error);
                })
        })
}
GetCountries() {
    this.adminStructService.GetCountries()
        .subscribe((res: ICountry[]) => {
            this.countries = res;
            this.countries.forEach((country: ICountry) => {
                //console.log(country.CountryName + "====================================================================================");
                this.countryItems.push(country.CountryName);
                this.selectCountry.itemObjects.push(new SelectItem({ id: country.CountryID, text: country.CountryName }));
            })
        }, error => {
            this.notificationService.printErrorMessage('Failed to load Countries. ' + error);
        });
}
//Tier
private tierValue: any = {};
private _tierDisabledV: string = '0';
private tierDisabled: boolean = false;
private tierItems: Array<any> = [];

private get countryDisabledV(): string {
    return this._countryDisabledV;
}

private set countryDisabledV(countryValue: string) {
    this._countryDisabledV = countryValue;
    this.countryDisabled = this._countryDisabledV === '1';
}

public countrySelected(countryValue: any): void {
    this.GetTiers(countryValue.id);
}

public countryRemoved(countryValue: any): void {
    //console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
}

public countryTyped(countryValue: any): void {
   // console.log('New search input: ', value);
}

public countryRefreshValue(countryValue: any): void {
    this.countryValue = countryValue;
}

//Tier
//Country Drop Down List
private get tierDisabledV(): string {
    return this._tierDisabledV;
}

private set tierDisabledV(tierValue: string) {
    this._countryDisabledV = tierValue;
    this.countryDisabled = this._countryDisabledV === '1';
}

public tierSelected(tierValue: any): void {
    //this.administrativeStructure.Parent = value.id;
    // this.router.navigate([value.id], { relativeTo: this.route });
}

public tierRemoved(tierValue: any): void {
    //console.log('Removed value is: ', value);
}

public tierTyped(tierValue: any): void {
   // console.log('New search input: ', value);
}

public tierRefreshValue(tierValue: any): void {
   // this.value = value;
}
}
```

The code in my view

```
<div class="row">
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                        <!--Single button with keyboard nav-->
                        <div style="width: 300px">
                            <strong>Select Country</strong>
                            <ng-select [allowClear]="true"
                                       [items]="countryItems"
                                       [disabled]="countryDisabled"
                                       (data)="countryRefreshValue($event)"
                                       (selected)="countrySelected($event)"
                                       (removed)="countryRemoved($event)"
                                       (typed)="countryTyped($event)"
                                       placeholder="No Country Selected">
                            </ng-select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <!--Single button with keyboard nav-->
                        <div style="width: 300px">
                            <strong>Select Tier</strong>
                            <ng-select [allowClear]="true"
                                       [items]="tierItems"
                                       [disabled]="tierDisabled"
                                       (data)="tierRefreshValue($event)"
                                       (selected)="tierSelected($event)"
                                       (removed)="tierRemoved($event)"
                                       (typed)="tierTyped($event)"
                                       placeholder="No Tier Selected">
                            </ng-select>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I will appreciate it very much if anyone can provide some samples on how to do this
 Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your `GetTiers` method you need might to reinitialize the `this.tierItems` array.

You can do the re-init first thing inside the subscribe method.

```
GetTiers(countryID: string) {
    this.tierService.GetTierSelect(countryID)
        .subscribe((res: TierSelectViewModel[]) => {
            this.tierItems = [];
            this.tiers = res;
            this.tiers.forEach((tier: Tier) => {
                this.tierItems.push(tier.TierName);
            });
        });
}
```

If that doesn't help, then the *ng2-select* doesn't support this scenario. You could add an `ngIf` to the second select and you set it to true when you have the data. That way the select will be recreated when the data is already there.

HTH

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked, but I had to add this line as well "this.selectTier = new SelectComponent(this.element, this.sanitizer);"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to get the cascading effect

```
GetTiers(countryID: string) {
    this.tierService.GetTierSelect(countryID)
        .subscribe((res: TierSelectViewModel[]) => {
            this.tierItems = [];
            this.selectTier = new SelectComponent(this.element, this.sanitizer);
            this.tiers = res;
            this.tiers.forEach((tier: Tier) => {
                console.log(tier.TierID + "====================================================================================" + tier.TierName);
                this.tierItems.push(tier.TierName);
                this.selectTier.itemObjects.push(new SelectItem({ id: tier.TierID.toString(), text: tier.TierName }));
            }, error => {
                this.notificationService.printErrorMessage("Failed to Load Tier Information " + error);
                })
        })
}
```

I reinitialsed the items array as suggested in a previous answer but I also had to add the following line

```
this.selectTier = new SelectComponent(this.element, this.sanitizer);
```

to create a new SelectComponent object. I however run into another problem.

The value of the id property of the SelectItem component seemed to be replaced by  the text property value. When you trigger the selected event "value.id in this case tierValue.id" returns the value for "tierValue.text".
logging to the console shows the values for the ID field (TierID)

[image]

So if the ID field is not of that much significance to your work as is my case this solution in my opinion will suffice for a cascading dropdown